# Android preferences Settings error in Android studio

Tags: android

**I made some setting Activity. And When I make the Intent, It's happened errors. It say's "
 *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;*"**

**and they said " alt_logout.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() " this code is problem. I don't Know what can I do. help me..**

```
else if(preference.getKey().equals("logout")){
            AlertDialog.Builder alt_logout = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            alt_logout.setMessage("Do You want to logout?");

        alt_logout.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // Action for 'Yes' Button
                        Intent Logout = new Intent(SettingActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(Logout);
                    }
                });

        alt_logout.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // Action for 'NO' Button
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert 

= alt_logout.create();
            // Title for Alet Dialog
        alert.setTitle("Logout");
        alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: please add the class definition where you are creating this dialog

Comment: may be your activity is not extending the AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alt_logout = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
```

To

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alt_logout = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```